# Sending Data from Arduino to Visual Studio Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, arduino-uno

I have four ADXL345 sensors run by Arduino UNO. I would like to display the data on Visual Studio C# Windows Form. In terms of Graph and data sheet. However, I encounter code issues as I'm not familiar with VS C#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i0LQ.png)

I created a Form and with all the buttons and display I wished to have. I have a running Arduino with data from four ADXL345 sensors. I need the data to be displayed on Windows Form, using it as a User Interface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//using ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.X1RangeAutoFormat;


namespace Vibration_Detection_System
{
    public partial class VibrationDetectionSystem : Form
    {
        private string StrParse;
        int TCA9548A;
        int Limit = 100;
        public VibrationDetectionSystem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         
        private void VibrationDetectionSystem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterToScreen();
            ButtonDisconnect.Enabled = false;
            ButtonConnect.Enabled = false;
            ButtonStartRecording.Enabled = false;
            ButtonStopRecording.Enabled = false;
            ComboBoxBaudRate.SelectedIndex = 3;

            ButtonSaveToExcel.Height = 50;

            for (int i=0; i<=30; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart4.Series["YRE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart4.Series["YRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["YRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;
            }

        }
        private void ButtonScanPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxPort.Items.Clear();
            string[] myPort = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
           
            if (myPort.Length > 0)
            {
                ComboBoxPort.Items.AddRange(myPort);
                ComboBoxPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ButtonConnect.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No COM ports detected", "Warning !!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                ComboBoxPort.Text = "";
                ComboBoxPort.Items.Clear();
                ButtonConnect.Enabled = false;
                ButtonStartRecording.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void ButtonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = int.Parse(ComboBoxBaudRate.SelectedItem.ToString());
            SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBoxPort.SelectedItem.ToString();

            try
            {
          
                TimerSerial.Start();
                //SerialPort1.Open();
                ComboBoxPort.Enabled = false;
                label1.Enabled = false;
                ComboBoxBaudRate.Enabled = false;
                ButtonScanPort.Enabled = false;
                ButtonConnect.Enabled = false;
                ButtonDisconnect.Enabled = true;
                ButtonStartRecording.Enabled = true;

                PictureBoxConnectionInd.Image = Vibration_Detection_System.Properties.Resources.Green;
                LabelStatus.Text = "Status : Connected";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to open the COM port: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void ButtonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBoxConnectionInd.Image = Vibration_Detection_System.Properties.Resources.Red;
            PictureBoxConnectionInd.Visible = true;
            LabelStatus.Text = "Status : Disconnect";

            ComboBoxPort.Enabled = true;
            label1.Enabled = true;
            ComboBoxBaudRate.Enabled = true;
            ButtonScanPort.Enabled = true;
            ButtonConnect.Enabled = true;
            ButtonDisconnect.Enabled = false;

            TimerSerial.Stop();
            TimerDataLogRecord.Stop();

            ButtonSaveToExcel.Enabled = true;
            ButtonStopRecording.Enabled = false;

           // try
           // {
            //    SerialPort1.Close();
           // }
           // catch (Exception ex)
           // {
           //     MessageBox.Show("Failed to close the COM port: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           // }
        }

        private bool isRecording = false;
        private void ButtonStartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort1.Open();
                isRecording = true;
                PictureBoxRecordInd.Image = Vibration_Detection_System.Properties.Resources.Green;
                PictureBoxRecordInd.Visible = true;
                ButtonStartRecording.Enabled = false;
                ButtonStopRecording.Enabled = true;
                ButtonSaveToExcel.Enabled = false;
                TimerDataLogRecord.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening the serial port: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
          if (isRecording)
            {
                string data = SerialPort1.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Received data: " + data);
                string[] values = data.Split(',');

                Console.WriteLine("Split data: ");
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }

                if (values.Length == 12)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
                    {
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                            values[0], values[1], values[2],
                            values[3], values[4], values[5],
                            values[6], values[7], values[8],
                            values[9], values[10], values[11],
                            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                            );
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

        private void ButtonStopRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort1.Close();
            isRecording = false;
            ButtonStartRecording.Enabled = true;
            ButtonStopRecording.Enabled = false;
            ButtonSaveToExcel.Enabled = true;
            TimerDataLogRecord.Stop();
            PictureBoxRecordInd.Visible = true;
            PictureBoxRecordInd.Image = Vibration_Detection_System.Properties.Resources.Red;
        }

        private void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["XLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["YLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart1.Series["ZLS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["XRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["YRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart2.Series["ZRS"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["XLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["YLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart3.Series["ZLE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), 0);
                if (chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["XRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1200;

                chart4.Series["YRE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart4.Series["YRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.AddY(0);
                if (chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.Count == Limit)
                {
                    chart4.Series["ZRE"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make use of SerialPort.DataReceived event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: I've made some edit on the code, but the data still wont display on DataGridView. Please assist. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your event handler `SerialPort1_DataReceived` is not triggered as you did not subscribe to it. You can do so by adding `SerialPort1.DataReceived += SerialPort1_DataReceived`.

You can test the following code which I have referenced and modified slightly from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Arduino
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeArduino();
        }

        private void InitializeArduino()
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += MySerialPort_DataReceived;

            mySerialPort.Open();
        }

        private void MySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadLine();

            this.richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(indata);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("hello from arduino");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Output

[image: Arduino data shown on rich text box c#]